# pathfinding algorithm bug in python

Tags: python

I have been using python's pathfinding module from pip but its not working
it seems to find a path that goes through obstacles (which is unacceptable for my videogame).

Here's the sample code:

```
from pathfinding.core.diagonal_movement import DiagonalMovement
from pathfinding.core.grid import Grid
from pathfinding.finder.a_star import AStarFinder

import random

blockpositions=[]

 def makegrid(x2,y2):
    grid=[]

    for x in range(x2):
        grid.append([])
        for y in range(y2):                
            if random.randint(1,5)==1:
                blockpositions.append((x,y))
                grid[x].append(0)
            else:
                grid[x].append(1)

     return grid

grid=makegrid(50,50)

startpos=(0,0)
endpos=(49,49)

finder = AStarFinder(diagonal_movement=DiagonalMovement.always)

grid2=Grid(matrix=grid)

start = grid2.node(startpos[0],startpos[1])
end = grid2.node(endpos[0],endpos[1])

path, runs = finder.find_path(start, end, grid2)

for x in path:
    if x in blockpositions:
        print("block in path!")

print(path)
```

returns the following:

```
block in path!
block in path!
block in path!
block in path!
block in path!
block in path!
block in path!
block in path!
block in path!
[(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 2), (4, 3), (5, 4), (6, 5), (7, 6), (8, 7), (9, 8), (10, 
9), (11, 9), (12, 10), (13, 11), (13, 12), (14, 13), (15, 14), (16, 15), (17, 16), (18, 
17), (19, 18), (20, 19), (21, 20), (22, 21), (23, 22), (24, 23), (25, 23), (26, 24), 
(26, 25), (27, 26), (28, 27), (29, 28), (30, 29), (31, 30), (32, 31), (33, 31), (34, 
32), (35, 33), (36, 34), (37, 35), (38, 36), (39, 37), (40, 38), (41, 39), (42, 40), 
(43, 41), (43, 42), (43, 43), (44, 44), (45, 45), (46, 46), (47, 47), (48, 48), (49, 
49)]
```

I know the grid is random so theres always a chance it will get stuck but ive
been running this algorithm in my videogame and get the same errors

Comment: `pathfinding` thinks of `x` as the column number and `y` as the row number. So the `path` you get is a list of (column, row) tuples, whereas your `blockpositions` is (row, column) tuples. You could try something like: `for y, x in path: if x, y in blockpositions: print('block in path!')` Does that still tell you you are going through blocks?

Comment: Also, not directly related, but you should make sure not to put a block on `startpos` or `endpos`.